# Strengthening and Weakening of pre and post conditions

Tags: java, oop, design-by-contract, preconditions, post-conditions

I have been reading into the topic of *Design By Contract* and so far have the following notes written:

```
When strengthening a condition, it means to make it 
more restrictive and weakening a condition is the opposite. 

A subclass' pre-condition is either weaker or the same as its super class'
A subclass' post-condition is either stronger or the same as its super class'
```

I would like to confirm an example to clarify my understanding.

```
class exampleA {
    int processInt(int exampleInt) {
        return exampleInt;
    }
}

class exampleB extends exampleA {
    int processInt(int exampleInt) {
        return exampleInt;
    }
}
```

Design by Contract says if the *precondition* for `processInt` in `exampleA` is, "`exampleInt` must be greater than 10," and the *postcondition* is, "the returned value is between 20 and 50," then the precondition of `exampleB`'s method `exampleInt` must either be the same or weaker, and the postcondition would be the same or stronger.

This means valid preconditions for `exampleB` could be,

- Greater than 0
- Greater than or equal to 0
- Greater than -100

But invalid preconditions would be,

- Greater than 20
- In the range of 20 to 500

Likewise, valid postconditions could be,

- Between 25 and 45
- Between 30 and 40

But invalid postconditions would be,

- Between 20 and 90
- Between 0 and 50
- Greater than 0

Is this a correct interpretation of Design by Contract? Also, I am learning this in Java, but I assume the concept applies to any language with OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your examples are correct; and yes, the same concepts apply to any language that supports polymorphism. Note that Design by Contract is also a part of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which prescribes even more restrictions on subtypes.